# Get value of checked radio

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to get the value of a radio-group with a specific name where a radio is checked.

But it doesn't give me the value.

Here is a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/qmHm7/

HTML:

```
 <input type="radio" name="txtCorrectAnswer" value="1">
 <input type="radio" name="txtCorrectAnswer" value="2">
 <input type="radio" name="txtCorrectAnswer" value="3">
 <button id="test">Test</button>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
      $('input:radio[name=txtCorrectAnswer]:checked').val();
 });
```

Any good suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g5wCb/1/

Answer (score 3):

your code is correct, you must put value in some where:

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/qmHm7/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(){
    alert($('input:radio[name=txtCorrectAnswer]:checked').val());
 });
```

you can learn about set value [here.](http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp)

Comment: Well, it didn't work, but now it does! Thanks for the input :)